# Flutter Google Map Lagging

Tags: flutter, google-polyline, gpx, google-maps-flutter

I have loaded GPX file and using Tracks and its points, I've draw Polylines on the map, but I found very huge performance drop in map, too much of lag while zooming or scrolling the map. I have loaded around 700 points in total of 30 Polylines.

So please help me to improve performance or suggest any other method for this kind of data.